# How can you make appear a status code as a response of an html form using a javascript fetch?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch, http-status-codes

I'm trying to create a form on html where you can enter a link (like: https://google.com) and when you submit it you can see the status code and see if there has been a problem or not.

My html code is for now really basic, and the name of my function would be retrieveStatusCode():

```
    <form action="./app.js" method="POST">

        <label for="url">Link : </label>

        <input type="url" name="url" id="url"
        placeholder="https://example.com">

        <input type="submit" onclick="retrieveStatusCode()">

    </form>
```

I also have a javascript function that does work separately:

```
let url="https://google.com";
let statusCode;

function retrieveStatusCode(){
    fetch(url)
        .then((resultat) => {
            if(resultat.status < 303) {
                console.log(resultat.status + ' Green')
            } else {
                console.log(resultat.status = ' Red')
            }
        });
}

 statusCode = setInterval(retrieveStatusCode, 1000);
```

But I can't find a way to link both codes in a way that the result of the function appears in my html page...
I'm quite new in javascript so it's probably obvious, sorry hehe

Comment: This won't work for lots of URLs because fetching is only possible if the server allows other domains to do so. Anyway, you need to call addEventListener() on your form and handle the submission event. Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/r4kmpuqw/

Comment: Also, CORS doesn't apply to iframes. It might be possible to check whether a URL is online if you set is as iframe src and handle the error event.

Comment: Oh I see, looks like I'll be having fun with this one haha
Thank you so much for your answer Chris!